# Facebook Graph API returns Shares instead of total count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am having an issue when trying to return the total_count number for our Like buttons.  Our application manages Like buttons and Open Graph tags, we have a few URLs we are trying to get the Like count for, but it is returning shares with no OG tag information.

For example:
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.fruitilike.com/products/shares-debug6/

Returns:

```
{
   "id": "http://www.fruitilike.com/products/shares-debug6/",
   "shares": 1
}
```

Example of how it should work:
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.fruitilike.com/products/apple

Returns:

```
{
   "id": "114182628680532",
   "name": "Apple",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/187789_114182628680532_2291233_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.fruitilike.com/products/apple",
   "likes": 1,
   "app_id": 102729306450470,
   "category": "Food",
   "is_published": true,
   "description": "The Apple. When it falls from a tree it generates gravity.",
   "about": "The Apple. When it falls from a tree it generates gravity."
}
```

Comment: It depends on the link. Even a trailing slash would make a difference. I guess teh first url has only shares but no likes or other info to it(was there an app id tied to it?) etc. where as the second url has these properties

Comment: Eswar, thanks. This is true but the problem is that Facebook used to return likes which was basically the total count, now they are returning shares.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with those results, this is due to fact that objects you compare have different types:

- `http://www.fruitilike.com/products/shares-debug6/` - [is `website`](https://graph.facebook.com/10151028992495250)
- `http://www.fruitilike.com/products/apple/` - [is `food`](https://graph.facebook.com/10150178707335357)

It totally ok to have different sets fields for different types of objects.

Comment: Hi Juicy - the issue is Facebook is not returning what used to be returned.  We tested with different types and everything is returning shares, where it used to return likes.

Comment: As of today Facebook is now returning shares for every URL on our site when you run https://graph.facebook.com/?id=URL  For Example run https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://bzzabout.it/75